# GWT/SmartGWT adding new language at Runtime

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization, smartgwt

I am using SmartGWT 3.0 and GWT 2.5. I know most of everything is pretty much compiled into corresponding javascripts by GWT. And this applies to i18n property files as well.

However i was looking for a way in which i can dynamically add a new language support by simply adding a new property file in the appropriate package.

I have tried that but it doesn't seem to work. Looking for any work around for this.

Thanks,

Vicky

Answer (score 0):

I also need something like this, because i dont want to recompile my application for message changes all the time, also i dont want to increase compile permutation.

I am thinking following solution will be close enought to replace Message interface

- Implement a servlet which  will return Map of values from server according to locale langauge
- Implement the message interface which will return values by calling the servlet with the locale language, and return values from the internal map.
- Use ETag caching for the servlet response in order to cache the message texts on the client side.

I am not sure if this will solve the issue but it seems easy and good solution to me. 
I am looking for any comments for the given solution or possible solutions for how not to increase compile permutations and need for compile each time a resource changes.